# Evaluate an integral related to binary expansion

Tags: real-analysis

For $x\in[0,1),$ consider its binary expansion$$x=0.a_1(x)a_2(x)\cdots.$$(for those whose binary expansion isn't unique, take the expansion that ends with $\cdots 000\cdots.$ Then for any lebesgue-integrable function $f:[0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1f(x)a_n(x)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$holds.

My ideas: Possibly we can use simple function to approximate $f(x)$, that is, if we can prove that for any lebesgue-measurable set $I\in[0,1)$ and the characteristic function $\chi_I$ the equation holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\chi_I=\begin{cases}1,\quad x\in I,\\0,\quad x\notin I.\end{cases}$ Then
$$a_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}\chi_{[\frac{2k-1}{2^n},\frac{2k}{2^n})}.$$
For $f(x)=\chi_I$, where $I\in[0,1)$ be an half-open interval, we have
$$\int_0^1f(x)a_n(x)\mathrm d x=\mu \left( I\cap\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}[\frac{2k-1}{2^n},\frac{2k}{2^n})\right)\right)=\begin{cases}\geq\frac{1}{2}\mu (I)-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\\\leq\frac12\mu (I)+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\end{cases},$$
Therefore, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1f(x)a_n(x)\mathrm dx=\frac12\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm dx$ for characteristic function of an half-open interval.

Let $\mathscr A=\{R\subset[0,1):\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1\chi_R(x)a_n(x)\mathrm dx=\frac12\int_0^1\chi_R(x)\mathrm dx\}.$ Then $[a,b)\in \mathscr A, \forall 0\leq a<b\leq 1.$

Suppose $\{U_n\}$ is a sequence of disjoint subset in $\mathscr A$. By the monotone convergence theorem,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}U_i}a_n\mathrm d \mu=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\int_{U_i}a_n\mathrm d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{U_i}a_n\mathrm d\mu=\frac12\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}U_i\right),$$
hence $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^\infty U_i\in\mathscr A$, $\mathscr A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing all the half-open interval in [0,1), and $\mathscr A$ contains all Borel sets.

Therefore, the proposition holds for simple functions.

For $f(x)\in \mathcal L^1,f\geq 0,$ approximate $f$ by a sequence of simple function $\{\varphi_n\}$, such that $0\leq\varphi_1\leq\varphi_2\leq\cdots\leq f$, and $ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\varphi_n=f\quad \mu$-a.e.[0,1). Hence $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists M>0$ such that $\forall m\geq M,\int_0^1f-\varphi_n\mathrm dx<\frac\epsilon 3.$ Since $\varphi_n$ are simple functions, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1\varphi_k(x)a_n(x)\mathrm dx=\frac12\int_0^1\varphi_k(x)\mathrm dx$. Fix $k>M$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N, \left|\int_0^1\varphi_k(x)a_n(x)\mathrm d x-\frac12\int_0^1\varphi_k(x)\mathrm d x\right|<\frac\epsilon3.$ When $n>N$,
$$\begin{aligned}\left|\int_0^1f(x)a_n(x)\mathrm dx-\frac12\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm dx\right| \leq&\left|\int_0^1f(x)a_n(x)\mathrm dx-\int_0^1\varphi_k(x)a_n(x)\mathrm dx\right| \\ &+\left|\int_0^1\varphi_k(x)a_n(x)\mathrm dx-\frac12\int_0^1\varphi_k(x)\mathrm dx\right| \\ &+\left|\frac12\int_0^1\varphi_k(x)\mathrm dx-\frac12\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm dx\right| \\ \leq&3\cdot\frac\epsilon3=\epsilon.\end{aligned}$$
Therefore, the proposition holds for all non-negative integrable function $f$.

For an arbitrary integrable function $f$, write it as $f=f^+-f^-$.